# Turning Head-Light Badminton Rackets into Head-Heavy

Tags: racket, badminton

I've bought my share of badminton rackets over the past few decades. The last ones were all quite head-light. Nowadays, I'm favouring head-heavy rackets.

Are there ways to turn my head-light racket collection into even-balanced or head-heavy rackets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Lead Tape

This is the best solution there is. Having read **[this](http://badminton-coach.co.uk/4973/victor-bravesword-12-badminton-racquet-review/)** racket review from **[Paul Stewart](https://plus.google.com/u/1/113734145071389375695/about)** about making a racket more head-heavy, I immediately ordered some tape:

[image]
The tape comes with a self adhesive side, allowing you to stick it everywhere. According to the description, 4 inch / 10 cm would yield approximately 1 gram.

### Usage

I chose the following areas to stick the lead tape on:

[image]

Best is to stick it on the inside of the frame. This will give less problems when the racket needs to be restrung and the forces act upon the tape or pass by it:

[image]

My attempt to use the outside of the frame works, but after a few training sessions, the tape will gradually lose its adhesive power:

[image]

### Notes

- wear protective gloves when applying the lead tape. Traces of lead, isn't something you want to accumulate.
- Adding to much weight in the top, will dramatically influence the racket behaviour. Start by adding some to the sides.
- Apparently, this technique is quite common for tennis rackets to be used.

### Note

I'm not affiliated to the vendor mentioned in the racket review.

Answer (score 0):

Tape a penny (2.5 grams), tiny metal washer or other low-profile but relatively heavy object to the shaft's T-joint. Warning- tape it very well or else it will eventually come off as a flying projectile toward your opponent!